# Send email with nodemailer, and insert form data into mysql db

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, post, nodemailer

Trying to setup a form that receives user input for a beta testing email list, which will send me an email with the user's information, and store the same form data into a mysql database.

I have the mysql connection and query inside the same route as the nodemailer objects, but when the form is submitted I get an error saying that "admin is not defined". This is the admin inside the transporter object. I thought it might cause problems if two different objects (tranporter and connection) have the same property name, so I changed the conventional nodemailer 'user' inside the transporter to 'admin'.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mysql = require("mysql");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

// send "Beta" email when user signs up to the email list using the "Beta" form
app.post("/register", function(req, res){
    // connect to database
    const connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: "localhost",
        user: "root",
        password: "PASSWORD",
        database: "DATABASE_NAME"
    });

    // insert statement
    let insert = "INSERT INTO Beta_Testers(First_Name, Last_Name, Beta_Email) VALUES ('" + req.body.First_Name + "', '" + req.body.Last_Name + "', '" + req.body.Beta_Email + "')";

    // execute the insert statement
    connection.query(insert);

    // disconnect from database
    connection.end();

    // nodemailer objects
    let mailOpts, transporter;

    // email transporter
    transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
        port: 3000, // changed from 465
        secure: true,
        auth: {
            admin: "GMAIL_USER",
            pass: "PASSWORD"
        }
    });

    // email credentials
    mailOpts = {
        from: req.body.First_Name + " " + req.body.Last_Name + " &lt;" + req.body.Beta_Email + "&gt;",
        to: admin,
        subject: "You have a new BETA tester!",
        text: `${req.body.Beta_Email} has signed up to be a BETA tester for WEBAPP_NAME. Please confirm sucessful registration into DATABASE_NAME.`
    };

    // send email and verify contact
    transporter.sendMail(mailOpts, function(err, res) {
       if (err) {
           res.render("contact-failure");
       } else {
           res.render("contact-success");
       }
    });
});
```

```
ReferenceError: admin is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Error is in : "to: admin"

It should contain an email to which email will be sent. These are the mail_options and the option "to" need to be set with an email like "abc@xyz.com".

You can set :-

to: req.body.email

Comment: I changed the value of "to" to a string and it worked, thanks!